# Tweepy connection error 10053 after running for a while

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I have been using Tweepy with Python 3 and needed to get the followers list of some famous handles for my learning.

Here is my code:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import time

consumer_key = 'x
consumer_secret = 'y'
access_token = 'a'
access_secret = 'b'
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
users = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name='realmadrid', count=200).items()
while True:
    try:
        user = next(users)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60 * 15)
        user = next(users)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    with open('BJP_Followers3.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(user.screen_name)
        f.write('\n')
    print(user.screen_name)
```

Now, as we know I can get at most 3000 followers in given 15 mins time so I make it to sleep for 15 mins and then it runs and fetches another 3000 followers.

Now after this I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 391, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1171, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 313, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 374, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 751, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 623, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 334, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 391, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1171, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 313, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 374, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 751, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 623, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 
'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.4.egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 187, in execute
    proxies=self.api.proxy)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 473, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 
'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\MB\Data Mining\timeline.py", line 21, in <module>
    user = next(users)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.4.egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 49, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.4.egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 197, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.4.egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 75, in next
    **self.kargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.4.egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy-3.6.0-py3.4.egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 189, in execute
    raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(10053, 
'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine', None, 10053, None))
```

Now, I want to know the reason as well as a solution for this problem I am facing.

Comment: I am .99 sure that IDLE is not involved, but to make sure, if you have not done so already, run this directly with Python from the console (Command Prompt) with `> python mytweep.py` in the appropriate directory.  Also, is this behavior consistently reproducible or a one-time occurrence?

Comment: I used it in Windows powershell too and its giving me same error after 30 mins(2*15mins window)

Comment: I see two possibilities: 1. the connection is closed at the first TweepError and you do not find out until 15 min later; 2. the connection is closed during the 15 min because of inactivities.  Either way, I would try getting just a few items and then sleeping a short time so you never get the exception and are never inactive very long.  Also, opening and closing the file repeatedly may not be a good idea.  I would put the loop inside the `with` block.  (I do not know much specifically about tweepy.)

Comment: Twitter doesn't allow service more than 3000 requests in a given 15mins time window hence I need to make my code sleep for 15mins. Removed the file opening from loop and made it outside.
Still no luck in this.

Comment: My suggestion was to spread those 3000 requests over each time window with multiple shorter sleep instead of blasting them as fast as possible.

Comment: Hey @panga30 , did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem. I am trying to get millions of followers' ids from a Twitter account, my script runs for a couple of hours, but then I get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know. Last option that I used is using very high speed internet with least interference for which I went to my laboratory, there I ran the code  successfully for about 2 days.
I guess internet connection and firewall should be checked.